# Vue setting 2 conditions with v-if

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm practicing Vue and got problem, is it possible to set 2 conditions using v-if? I mean this is my code:

So basically is it possible to set two conditions using && or it should be done some different way?

UPDATED FULL CODE:

I tried 3 methods, inside template, methods and computed methods, all of them check only one condition

with your help guys I kinda modified it and now it works! Thank you all so much for help but there is last thing, in console log it shows me: "Uncaught TypeError: _vm.validated is not a function",
 it is shown doesn't matter if validation is correct or not

```
<template>
  <div id='add-blog'>
      <h2>Add news Blog Post</h2>
      <form v-if='is_validated'>
          <label>User</label>
          <input type='text' v-model.lazy='user' required />
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type='password' v-model.lazy='password' required />
          <button v-on:click.prevent='validated'>Check me</button>
      </form>
      <div v-else>
          <p>error</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      user: "",
      password: "",
      is_validated: true,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    validated() {
      if (this.user == 'name' &&  this.password == '111') {
          return this.is_validated = false;
      }
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Well, have you ran it? What you have should work. Any valid javascript expression can go in there, if I remember correctly.

Comment: yes it's possible but i recommend to do not put logic inside template, use a computed property instead

Comment: @Zirek , which Vue version you use?, because that suppose to work 
Have you tried v-mode without `.lazy`

Comment: @mooga I'm using Vue 2.5.11, the thing is that it checks only first condition but doesn't check second one

Comment: @Zirek have you tried with `!==`. Regarding it's string

Comment: @mooga unfortunatelly I tried and same it checks only one condition... I'm gonna update first post and paste whole my code there, perhaps I miss something and that's the problem

Comment: Do you have the Vue devtools? If `user != 'name'` evaluates to true, then the second condition will not be evaluated at all because it will be short circuited. You can also add `{{ user != 'name' }}` to your code to check what that evaluates to.

Comment: @KamilJarosz I don't have devtools but actually if I have && between two conditions shouldn't it check if both conditions are true?

Comment: @Zirek, I'm sorry, I made a mistake above. I meant to say when `user != 'name'` evaluates to *false*, the second will not be checked. It does not get checked because it is unnecessary. If `user != 'name'` is false, the entire condition is always false.

Comment: @Zirek, have you tried to remove `.lazy`

Comment: @mooga I tried, without .lazy, it shows second div immediately after one condition is true, with .lazy, it at leasts waits until I click enter or tab

Comment: @Zirek, I have updated my answer , try it with flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried instead to make a `flag` for the complete form

**Update**:

```
<template>
  <div id='add-blog'>
      <h2>Add news Blog Post</h2>
      <form v-if='is_validated'>
          <label>User</label>
          <input type='text' v-model.lazy='user' required />
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type='password' v-model.lazy='password' required />
          <button @click='validated()'>Check me</button>
      </form>
      <div v-else>
          <p>error</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      user: "",
      password: "",
      is_validated: true,
    };
  },
  methods(): {
    validated() {
      if (this.user == 'name' &&  this.password == '111') {
         this.is_validated = false
      }
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Should be a computed property, not a method

Comment: your solution works well after I connected it with button:) thank you! but could you only check out as I updated my code and It shows me error event validation is running correctly

Comment: @Zirek because you use it at computed , you should use it in `methods: {
}`

Comment: @Zirek, ur welcome , don't forget to mark it as solution

Answer (score 2):

You surely can write complex expressions inside a v-if statement. As per the official documentation about [expressions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions) and directives in vue

> Directive attribute values are expected to be a single JavaScript
> expression

For what I see in your example it might be that your single file component does not match the proper structure. If you take a look at the single file component [guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)

You'll see that your component needs a  tag and inside you should write your template using your favorite templating language. Also it will be cleaner if you put your condition inside of a computed property. If we take all that into account, you could achieve your goal with a code similar to this one:

```
<template>
 <div>
   <form v-if="showForm">
      <label>User</label>
      <input type='text' v-model.lazy='user' required />
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type='password' v-model.lazy='password' required />
   </form>
   <div v-else>
     <p></p>
   </div>
 </div><!-- it's a good practice to have only one root element -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
        user:'',
        password:''
    };
  },
  computed: {
   showForm () {
     return user != 'name' && password != '111';
   }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: the problem is that again, it checks only one condition, so if I write in user area 'name' , it shows me second div without waiting for password, same if I skip user and just write '111 into password area, it also shows second div without user, and it is same doesn't matter if I write it inside v-if='', or if I use computed property

Comment: I was checking again the condition and it might be that the expression you're using may be causing the problem. Could you try with a double '=' sign so that you're expression looks like this
user !== 'name' && password !== '111';

Comment: I have tried with != and !== as well, unfortunately effect is still the same

Comment: @Zirek What you're describing is the expected behavior for the structure of that if statement. When you enter 'name' in user area, the div shows because the password is an empty string and '' != '111'. So both sides evaluate to true. If you're wanting the show/hide to only happen when the user has entered text in both boxes, use: user != 'name' && password != '111' && user != '' && password != ''

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to put your logic inside the script section and only call properties and methods in your template :

```
   <form v-if="validated">
      <label>User</label>
      <input type='text' v-model.lazy='user' required />
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type='password' v-model.lazy='password' required />
  </form>
```

the computed property 'validated' will check the provided input and return a boolean if there are valid:

```
     <script>
       export default {
             data() {
                return {
                user:'',
                 password:''
               };
          },
      computed:{
         validated(){return this.user != 'name' && this.password != '111'}
         }
        };
   </script>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      user: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    validated() {

      if (!this.user && !this.password) {
        return true;
      } else if (this.user !== 'name') {
        if (!this.password) return true
        else if (this.password !== '111') return true
        else return false

      } else if (this.user == 'name') {
        if (!this.password) return true
        else if (this.password !== '111') return true
        else return false
      } else if (this.password !== '111') {
        if (!this.user) return true
        else if (this.user !== 'name') return true
        else return false

      } else if (this.password == '111') {
        if (!this.user) return true
        else if (this.user !== 'name') return true
        else return false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<!-- Add this after vue.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>



<div id="app" class="container">
  <div v-if="validated">
    <form>
      <label>User</label>
      <input type='text' v-model.lazy='user' required />
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type='password' v-model.lazy='password' required />

    </form>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <p>Error !</p>
  </div>
</div>
```